# Error while executing assetic dump (parse error: failed at `&:extend(.clearfix all);`)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, frameworks

I was trying to install bootstrap to symfony2. Everything went well until I tried the assetic:dump --force command.

Here's my assetic configuration"

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        cssembed:
          jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
        yui_js:
          jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
        lessphp:
          file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
          apply_to: "\.less$"
    assets:
        jquery_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
            filters: [?yui_js]
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/transition.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/alert.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/modal.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/tab.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/popover.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/button.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/affix.js'
            filters: [?yui_js]
        bootstrap_less:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
            filters: [lessphp,cssembed]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I resolved it changing the "leafo/lessphp" version in `composer.json`:

From:

```
 "leafo/lessphp": "~0.3"
```

to:

```
 "leafo/lessphp": "~0.3.9"
```

Comment: I was following this tutorial [Symfony2 Tutorial Part 4 Twig and Bootstrap](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5om81wXYIns)

I had to change my Bootstrap version to "3.0.0". The Author's blog suggested "3.0.3" however using "leafo/lessphp":"~0.3.9" and "0.4.0" I was getting other issues.

Overall changing the bootstrap version to "3.0.0" fixed my issues

Comment: I was also following the same tutorial as yours. I just followed the solution above and I got mine fixed.

Comment: @seven-phases-max  says: There's [less.php](http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/) compiler that supports current Bootstrap versions.

Comment: I changed to: "twbs/bootstrap:v3.0.0" and "leafo/lessphp": "~0.3.9" and other error came again:   [Exception]                                                                  
  parse error: failed at `.size(@width; @height) {` C:/xampp/htdocs/proyectos  
  /authentication-provider/app/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/less/mixins.less on l  
  ine 47. Any suggestions?

Comment: !!! Issue solved for "oyejorge/less.php": "~1.5", instead of using "leafo/lessphp": "~0.3.9". Some sites already don't recommend using "leafo" anymore, it'll not extend support for future bootstrap versions. Bootstrap version: "twbs/bootstrap:v3.0.0" still remains as preferred. Read this: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/557