# Installing Bootstrap theme in Symfony 2 project

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am looking at installing [this theme](http://bootswatch.com/superhero/) in my SF2 project, and I note that there are 4 files at the top of the page to download, namely:

- bootstrap.min.css
- bootstrap.css
- variables.less
- bootswatch.less

I have the less.php (`oyejorge/less.php`) parser successfully installed along with bootstrap itself, and I have Assetic setup compressing all my CSS together and outputting this to the page:

`<link href="/app_dev.php/css/425e28c.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

However, I would like to install the Superhero theme in the link above but I can't find any tutorials on how to do this? Is it just a case of overwriting `variables.less` and importing `bootswatch.less`?

Comment: Bootswatch themes overwrite the bootstrap css, so ultimately you don't load both files - only the theme file.

Comment: I have spent many hours in search for apparent JS error just to find that I had included BS twice (original + theme)...

Comment: @skrilled So I assume I need to keep `twitter/bootstrap` in my composer.json, but where do I replace the bootstrap css with the Bootswatch theme. That was my question really...I have used bootstrap before, but I am somewhat of a SF2 noob. Thanks.

Comment: @jperovic Thanks for the tip, i'll be sure not to include both. Do you know where I put `bootswatch.less` files that the theme provides?

Answer (score 1):

Also read the Usage and Customization sections of the docs at https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch.

If you want to use the theme as is (without customization) you only should include the bootstrap.min.css OR bootstrap.css into your HTML:

```
<link href="/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Alternatively you can compile your own version of the theme:

1. Download Bootstrap's source files at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download
2. In the source files replace the less/variables.less file with that download from bootswatch
3. copy the bootswatch.less into the less directory of the bootstrap sources files
4. Than, open the less/bootstrap.less and add the following line of code at the end of this file: `@import "bootswatch"`
5. compile the modified bootstrap as described at: [Error while executing assetic dump (parse error: failed at `&:extend(.clearfix all);`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747631/error-while-executing-assetic-dump-parse-error-failed-at-extend-clearfix-a)

Also notice that Bootstrap adds the autoprefixer for vendor prefixes into their build process. The vendor prefix mixins in less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less are deprecated as of v3.2.0. So you should add https://packagist.org/packages/bit3/assetic-autoprefixer to your  assetic configuration too.