# part_1 css file being created by Assetic but not shown in source

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am trying to configure a Bootstrap theme with Assetic in my SF2 project, however I am experiencing an issue when doing a dump with Assetic.

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        cssembed:
          jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
        yui_js:
          jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
        #lessphp:
         # file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
          #apply_to: "\.less$"
    assets:
        jquery_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
            filters: [?yui_js]
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/transition.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/alert.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/modal.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/tab.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/popover.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/button.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/affix.js'
            filters: [?yui_js]
        bootstrap_less:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootswatch.less'
            filters: [cssembed]
```

When I do a `assetic:dump` I get a "part_1" file:

```
18:04:02 [file+] /var/www/vhosts/dev/dev_ayrshireminis/app/../web/assetic/bootstrap_less_bootstrap_1.less
18:04:02 [file+] /var/www/vhosts/dev/dev_ayrshireminis/app/../web/assetic/bootstrap_less_bootswatch_2.less
18:04:02 [file+] /var/www/vhosts/dev/dev_ayrshireminis/app/../web/css/425e28c.css
18:04:02 [file+] /var/www/vhosts/dev/dev_ayrshireminis/app/../web/css/425e28c_part_1.css
```

Is there a way I can get this working so I have include all the Bootstrap code to allow me to import this theme?

However, this doesn't show up in the source - only 425e28c.css does.

Answer (score 0):

You should compile only one less file. This less file should import your other less files.
For instance project.less which contains the following lines of code:

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "variables";
@import "bootswatch"
```

Now use:

bootstrap_less:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/project.less'
            filters: [cssembed]

See also: [Installing Bootstrap theme in Symfony 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065934/installing-bootstrap-theme-in-symfony-2-project/26192805)