# Play 2.2.1 using LESS (bootstrap.less and bootswatch.less). Theme wont load correctly

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, less

I cant figure out how to correctly work with LESS inside Play 2.2.1 framework.
What i want is to load some theme, for example http://bootswatch.com/amelia/

So basically i download bootstrap LESS and put it in the "assets/stylesheet/bootstrap" and also variables.css and bootswatch.css form "amelia" theme and placed in "assets/stylesheet".

From the official play 2.2.1 documentation http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/AssetsLess
my .**sbt** look like:

```
name := "bla bla"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache
)     

play.Project.playScalaSettings

play.Keys.lessEntryPoints <<= baseDirectory { base =>
   (base / "app" / "assets" / "stylesheets" ** "main.less")
}
```

**main.less**

```
@import "variables.less";

@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

@import "bootswatch.less";
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

So for example:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Success</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Link</button>
```

From amelia theme i should get following: [image]

But i only can see bootstrap defaults:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also read [Installing Bootstrap theme in Symfony 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23065934/installing-bootstrap-theme-in-symfony-2-project/26192805)

The problem seems the main.less file, you should import the variables.less after importing bootstrap.less as follows:

**main.less**

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
@import "variables.less";
@import "bootswatch.less";
```

For Less variables counts **last declaration wins** rule. The values of the variables in the theme's variables.less file are redeclared with that from the bootstrap/variables.less file when you import bootstrap.less after variables.less.